# Autocompile Pug(jade) in Atom?

Tags: pug

I'm working with Atom, and looking for a Jade/Pug compiler for Atom. 
What's is the best resource at the moment?

Do I need to add a plugin, or install this in NodeJS?

I need a Pug version and a copy of the compiled source.

Comment: Prepros.io is pretty great. Separate application for compiling.

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin](https://atom.io/packages/jade-autocompile) looks like it might do what you want to achieve.

Alternatively, yes, you can install the Pug compiler through the NodeJS Package Manager (`npm install pug`). Then you'll have to set up a script to compile the Pug code (see [the Pug documentation page on 'Getting Started'](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)). You can use an Atom plugin like [`script`](https://atom.io/packages/script) to run that compilation-script you just created.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Guys,

Did al little bit more research, and found out the CodeKit app in the store. Works great with pug, and all Sass/SCSS processors.